# jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a field draggable, and another one droppable. Now, when the draggable field is dragged to the droppable field, that draggable field move to the other one, while a few other fields will become the same type as the second one was. In case it is dragged to any other fields, it's position is reverted.

In short, I am trying to make an jQuery chess.

So far I have achieved to make one field draggable and the other one droppable, but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code? (or better, a jsfiddle example).

Answer (score 0):

To make a draggable revert to its original position you simply have to write:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: true });
```

You can look this up here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert

The jQuery UI demos are very helpful way to understand how everything works, and helped me a lot.

Comment: I already know that, but thanks anyway. What I am trying to say is that is not the point. The box would be reverted even though the move was legal.

Comment: You could try if(moveLegal == true){$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: false});} else{...}

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but I guess you want something like this? 
If not, you need to be more specific about your problem and show some code.
[Draggable example](http://jsfiddle.net/ghdekker/k68vj/1/)